# How to disable md-swipe when form validation=false in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, material-design, angular-material

I am new to Angular JS and I have multiple tabs and each tab contains a form.

I want md-swipe-left/right to be enabled or a successful function call to "submit" in tabs only when form input fields are true.

**Code**

```
<md-tabs md-swipe-content="true" ng-if={"form.valid" ? md-swipe-left="Submit()" md-swipe-right="Submit()"}>
```

Comment: So doy you want enable/disable md-swipe-content depending on if the form is valid or not, and in case is valid, call a submit() function when you swipe to both left or right?

Comment: Yes,you are right.Is it possible?

Comment: a partial solution but only swipe left is working and not the other 2 functions.Can anyone help me with that?                                                 ng-if="form.$valid" ? 'md-swipe-left="Submit()" && md-swipe-right="Submit()"' : 'Error()' "